# PHP search subarray in array with specific key

Tags: php, arrays, search, php-5.5

I need to navigate this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [isComplex] => 1
            [condition] => and
            [predicates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [isComplex] => 1
                            [condition] => and
                            [predicates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [isComplex] => 1
                                            [condition] => and
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [isComplex] => 
                                                            [field] => NAME
                                                            [operator] => startswith
                                                            [value] => as
                                                            [ignoreCase] => 1
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [isComplex] => 
                                                            [field] => MAIN_PHONE
                                                            [operator] => startswith
                                                            [value] => 06
                                                            [ignoreCase] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [isComplex] => 
                                            [field] => COD_FISC
                                            [operator] => startswith
                                            [value] => 98
                                            [ignoreCase] => 1
                                        )
//array multi
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [isComplex] => 
                            [field] => id
                            [operator] => startswith
                            [value] => 12
                            [ignoreCase] => 1
                        )

                )

        )


)
```

the result that I want to obtain is having only arrays with key Field

Es:
results:

```
[0] => Array
  (
    [isComplex] => 
    [field] => NAME
    [operator] => startswith
    [value] => as
    [ignoreCase] => 1
   )
[1] => Array
 (
   [isComplex] => 
   [field] => MAIN_PHONE
   [operator] => startswith
   [value] => 06
   [ignoreCase] => 1
)
[2] => Array
(
  [isComplex] => 
  [field] => COD_FISC
  [operator] => startswith
  [value] => 98
  [ignoreCase] => 1
)
[3] => Array
(
   [isComplex] => 
   [field] => id
   [operator] => startswith
   [value] => 12
   [ignoreCase] => 1
)
```

Hope this code is clear. any suggestions? Tried in several modality, but still not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try with recursion:

```
$global_var;

function recursive($node)
{
    // grab informations into $global_var
   if(has_no_subnodes) return;
   else recursive($node->subField);
}
```

Comment: howto has_no_subnodes?

Comment: `if(!isset(predicates))`?